# Proving False with negative inductive types in Coq

Tags: infinite-loop, coq, non-termination

The third chapter of CPDT briefly discusses why negative inductive types are forbidden in Coq. If we had

```
Inductive term : Set :=
| App : term -> term -> term
| Abs : (term -> term) -> term.
```

then we could easily define a function

```
Definition uhoh (t : term) : term :=
  match t with
    | Abs f => f t
    | _ => t
  end.
```

so that the term `uhoh (Abs uhoh)` would be non-terminating, with which "we would be able to prove every theorem".

I understand the non-termination part, but I don't get how we can prove anything with it. How would one prove `False` using `term` as defined above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading your question made me realize that I didn't quite understand Adam's argument either. But inconsistency in this case results quite easily from Cantor's usual [diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) (a never-ending source of paradoxes and puzzles in logic). Consider the following assumptions:

```
Section Diag.

Variable T : Type.

Variable test : T -> bool.

Variables x y : T.

Hypothesis xT : test x = true.
Hypothesis yF : test y = false.

Variable g : (T -> T) -> T.
Variable g_inv : T -> (T -> T).

Hypothesis gK : forall f, g_inv (g f) = f.

Definition kaboom (t : T) : T :=
  if test (g_inv t t) then y else x.

Lemma kaboom1 : forall t, kaboom t <> g_inv t t.
Proof.
  intros t H.
  unfold kaboom in H.
  destruct (test (g_inv t t)) eqn:E; congruence.
Qed.

Lemma kaboom2 : False.
Proof.
  assert (H := @kaboom1 (g kaboom)).
  rewrite -> gK in H.
  congruence.
Qed.

End Diag.
```

This is a generic development that could be instantiated with the `term` type defined in CPDT: `T` would be `term`, `x` and `y` would be two elements of `term` that we can test discriminate between (e.g. `App (Abs id) (Abs id)` and `Abs id`). The key point is the last assumption: we assume that we have an invertible function `g : (T -> T) -> T` which, in your example, would be `Abs`. Using that function, we play the usual diagonalization trick: we define a function `kaboom` that is by construction different from every function `T -> T`, including itself. The contradiction results from that.